# Postgres invalid input error on SELECT statement

Tags: node.js, postgresql, supabase

I am using Supabase as my DB.

I have users table with `id` field being populated with uuid_generate_v4().

I also have table bank_ao with foreign key `bankId` pointed to users.id.

When I do following:

```js
const uuid = req.params.id //this 100% works correctly and returns UUID every time!

await supabase
      .from("bank_ao")
      .select()
      .eq("bankId", uuid);
```

I get this error

```json
{"code":"22P02","details":null,"hint":null,"message":"invalid input syntax for type bigint: \"914eda70-2ecf-49b0-9ea6-87640944ed16\""}
```

I don't have BIGINT field in my entire DB. I have checked 100x.

I also tried to add `'` around my `uuid` variable, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Could this be some error specific to Supabase?

Comment: Sorry, but the database is always right, you still have a bigint in your table. Check the error message: invalid input syntax for type bigint. Check the logfiles of your database to get the complete query, check everything again.

Comment: Any chance `bankId` used to be a type bigint and you changed it to a UUID type? Deleting the table and recreating it with its type as UUID might work.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have recreated table from scratch and there is no bigint 

Comment: @dshukertjr it was like that and I have recreated the table several times and still I have this error. I will try and make entirely new project, and if I still have the same issues I need to move to some other solution.

Comment: @Korovjov Could you share the table definition of `bank_ao`?

Comment: @dshukertjr Thank you for your amazing help. 


| table_name | column_name        | data_type                |
| ---------- | ------------------ | ------------------------ |
| bank_ao    | id                 | uuid                     |
| bank_ao    | bankId             | uuid                     |
| bank_ao    | appraisalOfficeId  | uuid                     |
| bank_ao    | appraisalOfficerId | uuid                     |
| bank_ao    | createdBy          | uuid                     |
| bank_ao    | createdAt          | timestamp with time zone |

Comment: @Korovjov Could you add it to the question? It is a bit hard to read when it's in the comments.

Comment: You can copy and paste the SQL statements you used to create the table, or a screenshot of the table if you created it with the table editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following.

Before I used UUID as my id column value, it used to be BIGINT. When I changed it, it didn't change in cache, or some other type of memory. So, it threw an error.

I fixed it by re-creating entire database (I tried with table first, but it didn't work).

I have read online that if this is local version of Supabase you can just restart Postgres and it works fine (https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/11891).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the UUID into text to compare it there:

```js
const uuid = 'e1bee290-45d1-4233-ad96-b9924288d64c'
const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY);
const { data: ret, error } = await supabase
.from('bank_ao')
.select()
.eq('bankId::text', uuid);

console.log(ret);
```

### Assuming table format as:

[image]

### Output:

> [
> {
> bankId: 'e1bee290-45d1-4233-ad96-b9924288d64c',
> created_at: '2023-02-08T16:03:21.064501+00:00',
> foo: 'bar',
> bar: { bar: 'foo' }
> }
> ]

Please note that for using BigInt in Javascript safely, then you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549311/how-to-use-bigint-safely-with-supabase-js/74549904#74549904) (similar approach).

Comment: I did this and it's still not working. I still get the same error. 

Comment: I did create these tables to test it here. There's something else that you are missing. Is your `uuid` a string?

I've added the test table above, so you can check it.